# Haskell types and typeclasses declaration

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, typeclass

I am trying to understand classes and instances in Haskell a bit better. Therefore I am looking into:

http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses

Here they recommend trying:

```
instance (Eq m) => Eq (Maybe m) where  
    Just x == Just y = x == y  
    Nothing == Nothing = True  
    _ == _ = False
```

But when I do i get the following output:

```
tryouts.hs:58:10: error:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Eq m => Eq (Maybe m) -- Defined at tryouts.hs:58:10
      instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Maybe'
```

1. How can I get past that and go instantiate my own typeclass-declarations?
2. The author argues taht the `(Eq m) => Eq` in front of the class is important to restrain the content of the instance. This is apparantly different than if you do it at the class level (e.g.) when you define `Eq`. I am however not sure I understand what the difference is. THis might be where I don't understand the difference between a typeclass and a regular class in OOP and the nature of 'inheritance' for the former.

Comment: `Eq (Maybe a)` is all defined (exactly as specified), so it makes no sense to create a new one.

Comment: That is the same conclusion I reached. But if I want to create a `Maybe2` for instance how would I go about it?

Comment: Sidenote: Write type signatures for your methods, this requires [`{-# Language InstanceSigs #-}`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/instances.html#instance-signatures-type-signatures-in-instance-declarations) at the top of your module. Then you can write `(==) :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Bool`.

Comment: So the `Eq` class is defined like `class Eq a where (==) :: a -> a -> Bool`. For your question 2, it might be interesting for you to think about what you would expect to see there if you wanted to this instance's constraint into the class. What  would your alternative class declaration look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How can I get past that and go instantiate my own typeclass-declarations?

The error says that in the module, it already contains such instance. In fact it is semantically exactly the same one, as we can see in the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Maybe.html#Maybe):

> ```
> data  Maybe a  =  Nothing | Just a
>   deriving ( Eq  -- ^ @since 2.01
>            , Ord -- ^ @since 2.01
>            )
> ```

The default way to implement `Eq` is that it returns `True` if the data constructors of the two items are the same, and that the parameters are, element-wise, equal.

You can define your own types, and then define instances, like for example:

```
data Maybe2 a = Nothing2 | Just2 a

instance Eq m => Eq (Maybe2 m) where  
    Just2 x == Just2 y = x == y  
    Nothing 2== Nothing2 = True  
    _ == _ = False
```

> The author argues that the `(Eq m) => Eq` in front of the class is important to restrain the content of the instance. This is apparantly different than if you do it at the class level (e.g.) when you define Eq. I am however not sure I understand what the difference is. THis might be where I don't understand the difference between a typeclass and a regular class in OOP and the nature of 'inheritance' for the former.

If you would use:

```
class Eq a => Eq (f a) where
    ...
```

Then it would mean that `Eq (Maybe a)` would imply `Eq a`, so it is the other way around. This would however never work, since if `Eq (Maybe Int)` would be an instance, then `Eq Int` is an instance, but `Eq Int` can only be an instance if somehow `Int ~ f a` (`Int` is the same type as `f a`), and `a` is an instance of `Eq`.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't really "redefine" `Eq` for `Maybe a` since it is already been defined in Prelude.  That being said, there may be a way that you can redefine it by `{-#LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}` and carefully import just enough types and type classes to avoid importing the file that contains the `Eq` definition for `Maybe a`, or perhaps you can use one of the pragmas to allow overlapping declarations, but I am not familiar with that so don't take my word on it.
2. `Eq m => Eq (Maybe m)` means that in order for `Maybe m` to be an instance of the `Eq` type class, `m` must already be an instance of `Eq`. This is quite natural, since in order to compare `Just a` and `Just b`, you need to able to compare `a` and `b`. As a result, you cannot compare equality for things like `Just (+)` and `Just (-)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach you can use to try to play with imported by default from `Prelude` stuff - use `hiding`. In this case it can look like this:

```hs
import Prelude hiding (Maybe, Just, Nothing)

data  Maybe a  =  Nothing | Just a

instance (Eq m) => Eq (Maybe m) where  
    Just x == Just y = x == y  
    Nothing == Nothing = True  
    _ == _ = False
```